# what kind of accuracy (rmse) can be expected by georeferencing a scanned image?

Tags: georeferencing

I am trying to understand what is the effective accuracy of a georeferenced image and how to attach a standard to the georeferencing process which can be used for future reference. To explain further, I am trying to assess what kind of RMSE would be acceptable when for example georeferencing an accurate architects drawing with an aerial image, or with a small scale landuse plan drawn with thick outlines using parcel data with an accuracy of plus/minus 1cm.

If I am using an inaccurate base map in which to base my passpoints, does the rms error have any meaning whatsoever? Logically, is it not so, that one can only use the rmse as a standard when the accuracy of the basemap can be certified? If the base map is not accurate, any passpoints referenced to it would be even less accurate and an RMS error meaningless.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Some info at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77772/1297 might help too.